# How to get parameter on Angular2 route in Angular way?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

**Route**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/companies/unionbank', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'companies/:bank', component: BanksComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/companies/unionbank' }
];
```

**Component**

```
const NAVBAR = [
  { 
    name: 'Banks',
    submenu: [
      { routelink: '/companies/unionbank', name: 'Union Bank' },
      { routelink: '/companies/metrobank', name: 'Metro Bank' },
      { routelink: '/companies/bdo', name: 'BDO' },
      { routelink: '/companies/chinabank', name: 'China Bank' },
    ],
  },
  ...
];
```

Example url: `http://localhost:8099/#/companies/bdo`

I want to get `String` **bdo**  in the example url above.

I'm aware that I can get the url by using window.location.href and split into an array. In that way, I can get the last parameter of the url above. However, I wanted to know if there's a proper way to do this in Angular.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 300, accepted):

#### Update: Sep 2019

As a few people have mentioned, the parameters in `paramMap` should be accessed using the common `Map`API:

To get a snapshot of the params, when you don't care that they may change:

```js
this.bankName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('bank');
```

To subscribe and be alerted to changes in the parameter values (typically as a result of the router's navigation)

```js
this.route.paramMap.subscribe( paramMap => {
    this.bankName = paramMap.get('bank');
})
```

#### Update: Aug 2017

Since Angular 4, `params` have been deprecated in favor of the new interface [`paramMap`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap). The code for the problem above should work if you simply substitute one for the other.

#### Original Answer

If you inject `ActivatedRoute` in your component, you'll be able to extract the route parameters

```js
    import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
    ...
    
    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}
    bankName:string;
    
    ngOnInit(){
        // 'bank' is the name of the route parameter
        this.bankName = this.route.snapshot.params['bank'];
    }
```

If you expect users to navigate from bank to bank directly, without navigating to another component first, you ought to access the parameter through an observable:

```js
    ngOnInit(){
        this.route.params.subscribe( params =>
            this.bankName = params['bank'];
        )
    }
```

For the docs, including the differences between the two [check out this link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and search for "*activatedroute*"

Comment: Is there a restriction where components loaded into a router-outlet of a parent component will see different ActiveRoute parameters - I've run into a case where the parent sees a parameter, but the contained components do not see the same parameter...

Comment: It was not working for me because I added the ActivatedRoute as a providers for my component. So, make sure you don't do that ! It's working like a charm with angular 4.2.4.

Comment: For `paramMap`, you should be using `params.get('bank')` instead.

Comment: What's the difference between `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('bank');` and `this.route.snapshot.params.bank;`?

Comment: with .get() you make sure you actually get the attribute - with .params.XXX you could get sth. from prototype chain - generic guidline: dont access properties but use the dedicated getter when there are some

Answer (score 28):

As of Angular 6+, this is handled slightly differently than in previous versions.  As @BeetleJuice mentions in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40276279/3443552), `paramMap` is new interface for getting route params, but the execution is a bit different in more recent versions of Angular.  Assuming this is in a component:

```
private _entityId: number;

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // ...
}

ngOnInit() {
    // For a static snapshot of the route...
    this._entityId = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    // For subscribing to the observable paramMap...
    this._route.paramMap.pipe(
        switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this._entityId = params.get('id'))
    );

    // Or as an alternative, with slightly different execution...
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) =>  {
        this._entityId = params.get('id');
    });
}
```

I prefer to use both because then on direct page load I can get the ID param, and also if navigating between related entities the subscription will update properly.

[Source in Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action)

Comment: Why would `switchMap` be required here? Won't the subscribe get called on direct page load as well?

Comment: @crush From the docs linked above: "You might think to use the RxJS `map` operator. But the `HeroService` returns an `Observable<Hero>`. So you flatten the Observable with the `switchMap` operator instead.

The `switchMap` operator also cancels previous in-flight requests. If the user re-navigates to this route with a new `id` while the `HeroService` is still retrieving the old `id`, `switchMap` discards that old request and returns the hero for the new `id`."

Answer (score 5):

This topic is already quite old, but still on top of my the search engine results. I am pretty sure the ways that have been shown here already work. But some of them are outdated or incomplete. So this is an up-to-date complete example, that hopefully helps you. I call the parameter receiving component **PersonComponent**. First part are your **Routes** most likely defined in **app.module.ts** (app-routing.module.ts):

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: "/", component: HomeComponent}, 
{path: "person/name/:personName", component: PersonComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Notice the **:personName** in the route for the PersonComponent, this is the key we have to look for you can call it however you please. Next use this route in the HTML part of another (or the same) component:

```
<a routerLink="person/name/Mario">This is Mario</a>
<a routerLink="person/name/Luigi">This is Luigi</a>
<a routerLink="person/name/Bowser">This is Bowser</a>
```

Here the **:personName** is replaced with actual names. Last one is reading this parameter in the **PersonComponent**

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.scss']
})
export class PersonComponent {

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const name = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('personName');
    console.log(name)
    //do whatever you want with it
  }
}
```

You can see that the **:personName** from the **Routes** is used as a key, to get the value from the **paramMap**.

Answer (score 4):

Since Angular 16 you can bind route info to component inputs, see the [link](https://itnext.io/bind-route-info-to-component-inputs-new-router-feature-1d747e559dc4).

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'companies/:name', component: CompaniesComponent },
]
```

Using components inputs:

```
@Component({})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {
    /* 
        We can use the same name as the query param
        Example url: http://localhost:4200/companies/my-bank
    */
    @Input() name?: string; // we can use the same name as the query param

    /* 
        Or we can use a different name
        Example url: http://localhost:4200/companies/my-bank
    */
    @Input('name') queryParam?: string; // we can also use a different name

    ngOnInit() {
        // do something with the query
    }
}
```

Comment: REMINDER: Do not forget to add `{ bindToComponentInputs: true }` into `RouterModule.forRoot` options for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for get route parameter:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe((qp) => {
      console.log('Get Router Params:', this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.bank);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

You can check more details of the route URL [here](https://kmgtech.blogspot.com/2021/10/how-to-get-route-url-in-angular.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with paramMap you can also go fancy and use a Route Resolver although this might be a bit overkill and is usually used to fetch data during the navigation process...

setup resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LastUrlPathResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {

  constructor(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){}

  resolve(): Observable<string> {
    return activatedRouteSnapshot.url[activatedRouteSnapshot.url.length-1]
  }
}
```

setup routes

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { NewsResolver } from './news.resolver';

import { TopComponent } from './top/top.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'top',
    component: TopComponent,
    resolve: { message: LastUrlPathResolver }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

use it like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ ... })
export class TopComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
  }
}
```

find more here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-route-resolvers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, surely you can get the param using the Angular way. Angular provides 2 ways to get the param value from the URL.

1. Using the ActivatedRoute from @angular/router. Please check below code for the same. (https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)

   this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
2. Using the paramMap Observable (https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap)

   this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
   this.id = +params.get('id')
   });

Please check documentation links as well. And before using this.router please import   ActivatedRoute from '@angular/router' for 1st option and import ActivatedRoute, ParamMap both for 2nd option. Below is the example.

```
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router'

import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router'
```