# Not able to get the parameters from the dynamic url in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, mean, dynamic-url

I'm trying to have a route called 'event' with parameter event_id in the URL.

app routing module has this

```
{ path: 'event/:event_id', component: EventComponent },
```

The component tries to get event_id from url using Activated route.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {
  event: JSON;
  id: String;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('that kind of madness can\'t be undone');
      console.log(params['event_id']); // checking result
    })
  }
```

console.log(params['event_id']) is giving an empty object as a result.

Comment: you are using `routeParams` and if you need to use `queryParams` you should have relative route definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameter on Angular2 route in Angular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275862/how-to-get-parameter-on-angular2-route-in-angular-way)

Comment: There are three different ways to use routing parameters and the syntax for each one is a bit different. So it's important to understand which type of parameter you need and use all of the syntax appropriate for that type. See a summary of the types and syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:eventId` isn't a query parameter, it would belongs to route parameter, so check `params` Observable on current activate route.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log('that kind of madness can\'t be undone');
  console.log(params['event_id']); // checking result
})
```