# Create and Edit operations in angular

Tags: angular

i'm implementing a component in `angular 5` that create my `foo` object and it work fine but after that i want to edit it, so i point the edit path to the same component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'foo/new', component: NewFooComponent },
  { path: 'foo/edit/:id', component: NewFooComponent },
  ...
];
```

my question is how to know in my `NewFooComponent.ts` if i'm in the `foo/new` path or in `foo/edit/:id` ?

And also is it the best approach ?

Comment: Can't you just test wether you have an `id` or not ?

Comment: You could try to get `id` with the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40276279/1009922).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is setting like `new` or `edit` as a param and check params using `ActivatedRoute`

So I'll set up the routes as follow :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'foo/:state', component: NewFooComponent },
  { path: 'foo/:state/:id', component: NewFooComponent },
  ...
];
```

and check by doing

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        if(params['state'] === 'new') { ... } 
        else {...}
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution but it will be simple to check just the id if is null, don't you think ?

Comment: Sure, if the id is available only on edit mode then yes, it is easier. I just assumed it was not.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ActivatedRoute` to get the router parameters navigate id the `id` property exists in the path

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){} 

ngOnInit(){
    // 'id' is the name of the route parameter
    if (this.route.snapshot.params['id']) { .... };
    else { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a bad design decision, your `NewFooComponent` is now doing the creation and the edit of something, and that violate the SRP, so maybe you should create a dedicate component for the editing and share the template if that is the duplication you are trying to avoid creating only one component.