# How to get param from user-friendly url?

Tags: angular, angular-router

For example i have this url: http://localhost/site/users/12/edit

How i can get number from url?

I use Angular v5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameter on Angular2 route in Angular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275862/how-to-get-parameter-on-angular2-route-in-angular-way)

Answer (score -1):

The parameters are stored under the variable `ActivatedRoute.queryParams` and you can access it by subscribing to it:

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data);
   });
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There's really no need. He asked how to get the param and i told him. But you're welcome to provide an explanation :)

Comment: the example of OP has no query params