# How to get url parameter using ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular

My route is:

```
{
    path: "events",
    component: SkeletonComponent,
    children: [
       {
        path: ':id',
        component: ViewEventComponent
      }     
    ]
}
```

Component is:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params);
   })
}
```

`Console.log()` gives me empty object `{}`

Comment: What does your URL look like, are you passing query params in the URL ?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/events/1

Comment: You need to pass query params after '?' and separated by '&', for example: /events/1?param1=3&param2=4

Comment: Without query params, you will get an empty object

Comment: Are you looking to get :id instead?

Comment: My parameter is `1` it is `:id` from route rule

Comment: Yes, I am looking :id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parameter on Angular2 route in Angular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275862/how-to-get-parameter-on-angular2-route-in-angular-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `activatedRoute.queryParams` will give you an object containing the query parameters.
If your url is `/events/1?param1=1&param2=2`, this object will be:

```
{ param1: '1', param2: '2' }
```

The query parameters are the key/value pairs given after `?` in the URL.

If instead you want your route parameters, such as `:id`, defined in your routing config, you have to use `activatedRoute.params` and not `activatedRoute.queryParams`. This will give an object like:

```
{ id: '1' }
```

for a route like `/events/1` where the route is defined as `/events/:id`.

Here is how you can get your `id` param:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params['id']);
   })
}
```

The value will be given as a string, you can convert it to a number with `Number(id)` or `+id`.

If you do not want to get an observable of the current route, you can also get a snapshot with:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
   const id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
   console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Ho to get `1` from url `localhost:4200/events/1 `?

Comment: I updated the answer, I also added an example using a snapshot if you do not want an observable of the route. Hope that helps!