# Routing with variable angular2?

Tags: angular

I need to route to another component, as you can see in the path, but I need to pass the variable this.a together. How can I do that in order to use this variable's value to the other component?

Component.ts

```
 import {Component, OnDestroy,OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';
    import { ParkingService } from '../../../services/parking.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';



    @Component({
        selector: 'ngx-homepage',
        styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.scss'],
        templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
        providers: [ParkingService]

      })

      @Injectable()
      export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {


        a:string;
      constructor (public parkingService: ParkingService, public root:Router) { 


      }
      ngOnInit(){


      }

            pass(passa)
              {

              this.a= passa.value;
              window.alert(this.a);
              this.parkingService.setUserToken(this.a);

              this.root.navigate(['/pages/iot-dashboard']);

              }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Angular docs you can see the answer in https://angular.io/guide/router#migrating-urls-with-redirects

```
pass(passa) {
    this.a= passa.value;
    window.alert(this.a);
    this.parkingService.setUserToken(this.a);
    this.root.navigate(['/pages/iot-dashboard', { userToken: this.a }]);
}
```

You can replace `userToken` in the object by the name of the variable you want to pass to the route

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your answer. How can I use this value at the reciever component. I want to print the value of "a" at the reciever component

Comment: You can find the response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275862/how-to-get-parameter-on-angular2-route-in-angular-way