# Not able to fetch data as per id from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I m trying to make angular application. But I'm facing a particular problem, whenever I'm clicking the button in flights.component.html, the specific data related to particular id is not displaying in checkin.component.html. Instead, it is rendering the whole data from the local JSON file.

My Code.

app-routing.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FlightsComponent } from './flights/flights.component';
import { CheckinComponent } from './checkin/checkin.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'flights',
    component: FlightsComponent,
    children: [{ path: 'checkin/:id', component: CheckinComponent }]
  },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

flights.component.html

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of flightListData">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{ item.flightName }}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <span class="margin-right-20">{{ item.source }}</span>
        <span class="margin-right-20">{{ item.stop }}</span>
        <span>{{ item.destination }}</span>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div>
      <span>Departure: {{ item.departure }}</span>
      <span>Arrival: {{ item.arrival }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        class="margin-right-20"
        (click)="clickHandler(item.id)"
      >
        Check In
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

flights.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import data from '../../data/data.json';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-flights',
  templateUrl: './flights.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flights.component.scss']
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
  flightListData: {
    id: number;
    flightName: string;
    source: string;
    destination: string;
    duration: string;
    stop: string;
    departure: string;
    arrival: string;
  }[] = data;

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  clickHandler(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['checkin', id], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
    });
  }
}
```

checkin.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of flightListData; let i = index">
  <p [id]="i">{{ item.flightName }}</p>
</div>
```

checkin.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import data from '../../data/data.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkin',
  templateUrl: './checkin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkin.component.scss']
})
export class CheckinComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  flightListData: {
    id: number;
    flightName: string;
    source: string;
    destination: string;
    duration: string;
    stop: string;
    departure: string;
    arrival: string;
  }[] = data;
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: In your checkin component you need to fetch the id again from the activatedRoute..

Comment: How would I fetch that. Can you give an example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275862/how-to-get-parameter-on-angular2-route-in-angular-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the id according to the id in the route. Here is some code, please let me know if this is working. Thank you.

checkin.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id =+ params['id'];        
    this.flightListData.filter( item => item.id === this.id);
    this.data = this.flightListData[this.id-1];
  });
```

checkin.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data;">
  <p>{{ item.flightName }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flightListData: {
    id: number;
    flightName: string;
    source: string;
    destination: string;
    duration: string;
    stop: string;
    departure: string;
    arrival: string;
  }[] = data;
```

You do not filter the data received from JSON file. Absolutely it should show all of the data.